# Installing google analytics in Xamarin Studio for Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, xamarin

I'm having trouble installing google analytics in Xamarin Studio, for android developement. (I have it working for ios).

Can someone point me to the correct installation steps? I've installed a nu-gen package for it, but I can't use the analytic name space. (My project does not know about it.

Thanks,
Gerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Via Nuget:**

Search for *Xamarin Google Play Services* - Analytics 27.0.0

```
PM> Install-Package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Analytics -Version 27.0.0
```

**Using:**

using Android.Gms.Analytics;

**Example:**

```
var TrackerId = "{my private Tracker Id}";
var myTracker = GoogleAnalytics.GetInstance(Application.Context).NewTracker(TrackerId);
myTracker.SetScreenName("MyXammyApp");
myTracker.Send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().Build());
```

Addition Info: http://www.google.com/analytics/mobile/